# WMAppManifest.xml Designer View Missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have Vs 2010 and working on a Wp7 app. I read on an [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that WMAppManifest.xml has a designer view but when I click on designer view it just loads up the .xml file.

Did they remove designer view or is something wrong with my Vs?

On a side note in the WMAppManifest.xml there is a title node. What does that refer to? Is that the name that will show up on the device?

Comment: Do you have a link to the msdn page? Perhaps they were talking about VS2012?

Comment: updated, don't see any mention of VS version.

Comment: I think it was introduced with VS2012 or WP SDK 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

The Graphical Manifest Designer was introduce with Visual Studio 2012. It's not available in 
Visual Studio 2010.

http://mobileosgeek.com/windows-phone-8-sdk-feature-graphical-manifest-designer/